# Same css selection produces a different result

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, vertical-alignment

Same css selection produces a different result. What am I missing here?

html:

```
<div class="cDiv">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
  <span class="cText"> Hello world </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cText {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cDiv > * {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/706/) is a jsFiddle.

After applying `vertical-align: middle;` to the `.cDiv > *` selection text gets moved to the middle as expected.

After applying `vertical-align: middle;` to the `.cText` selection text does not get moved to the middle as expected.

Both selections include the `span` containing the text, but only one selection affects it. I am not expecting such a behavior. Could someone explain this, please?

I want my selection by class being able to affect the text alignment as well.

Comment: _“Both selections include the span containing the text, but only one selection affects it.”_ - that’s not the case, you are drawing the wrong conclusions here. The span element gets `vertical-align: middle` set with _both_ versions. But only with the second one are you specifying it for the image as well - with the first version, you don’t, so the default value `baseline` gets applied for the image. _That_ is what is causing the two to display different, not that your selectors would not match the span element in both cases.

Comment: @misorude, ok. Why changing style on one element (image) affects styling on another element (span) ?

Comment: Because with vertical-align you specify an element’s alignment within the _line box_, and the image and the span are both in the same line box.

Comment: Please read and you will understand why you need to put vertical align on the image to affect the text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align - basically summed up by *To vertically align an inline element's box inside its containing line box.*  Also helpful: https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Comment: Ok. Thank you all.